# AccessViolation on LsaAddAccountRights

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke

I've been staring at this one too long...I'm getting an AccessViolation on my call to LsaAddAccountRights below.  I think I've included the relevant details.  Any help is appreciated!

The code that is causing the AccessViolation:

```
LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] userRights = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING[1];
userRights[0] = new LSA_UNICODE_STRING(privilegeName);

//add the right to the account
retVal = LsaAddAccountRights(
    hPolicy, 
    sidBufferHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
    userRights, 
    1);
```

The p/invoke declare is:

```
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, PreserveSig = true)]
    private static extern Int32 LsaAddAccountRights(
        IntPtr PolicyHandle,
        IntPtr AccountSid,
        LSA_UNICODE_STRING[] UserRights,
        Int32 CountOfRights);
```

hPolicy is set via the following code, which does work and yield a handle:

```
LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objAttrs = new LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES();

IntPtr hPolicy = IntPtr.Zero;

int access = (int)(
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_AUDIT_LOG_ADMIN |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_ACCOUNT |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_PRIVILEGE |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_CREATE_SECRET |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_GET_PRIVATE_INFORMATION |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_NOTIFICATION |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_SERVER_ADMIN |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_SET_AUDIT_REQUIREMENTS |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_SET_DEFAULT_QUOTA_LIMITS |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_TRUST_ADMIN |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_VIEW_AUDIT_INFORMATION |
            LsaAccessPolicy.POLICY_VIEW_LOCAL_INFORMATION
            );

int retVal = LsaOpenPolicy(
    IntPtr.Zero, // local machine
    ref objAttrs,
    access,
    out hPolicy);
```

sidBufferHandle is setup as follows:

```
SecurityIdentifier adminSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);
int sidLen = adminSid.BinaryLength;
byte[] sidBuffer = new byte[adminSid.BinaryLength];
adminSid.GetBinaryForm(sidBuffer, 0);
GCHandle sidBufferHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(sidBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);
```

LSA_UNICODE_STRING is setup as follows:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class LSA_UNICODE_STRING
    {

        public UInt16 Length;
        public UInt16 MaximumLength;
        public IntPtr Buffer;

        public LSA_UNICODE_STRING(string s)
        {
            this.Buffer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(s);
            this.Length = (UInt16)(s.Length * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);
            this.MaximumLength = (UInt16)((s.Length + 1) * UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);
        }

        ~LSA_UNICODE_STRING()
        {
            if (this.Buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(this.Buffer);
                this.Buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        public static string PtrToString(IntPtr p)
        {
            Int16 length = Marshal.ReadInt16(p);
            Int16 maxLen = Marshal.ReadInt16(p + 2);
            IntPtr pBuffer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(p + 4);

            char[] cvt = new char[length / UnicodeEncoding.CharSize];
            Marshal.Copy(pBuffer, cvt, 0, length / UnicodeEncoding.CharSize);
            return new string(cvt);
        }

    }
```

LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES is setup as follows (because it is not really used):

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int Length;
        public IntPtr RootDirectory;
        public UInt16 ObjectName_Length;
        public UInt16 ObjectName_MaximumLength;
        public IntPtr ObjectName_Buffer;
        public UInt32 Attributes;
        public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
        public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unmanaged function declaration is:

```
NTSTATUS LsaAddAccountRights(
  _In_  LSA_HANDLE PolicyHandle,
  _In_  PSID AccountSid,
  _In_  PLSA_UNICODE_STRING UserRights,
  _In_  ULONG CountOfRights
);
```

Let's concentrate on the `UserRights` parameter. That is of type `PLSA_UNICODE_STRING`. Described as:

> Pointer to an array of LSA_UNICODE_STRING structures.

And then the structure:

```
typedef struct _LSA_UNICODE_STRING {
  USHORT Length;
  USHORT MaximumLength;
  PWSTR  Buffer;
} LSA_UNICODE_STRING, *PLSA_UNICODE_STRING;
```

So, `PLSA_UNICODE_STRING` is a pointer to a struct.

The main problem here lies in how you have declared `LSA_UNICODE_STRING` in your C#. You've declared it as a C# class. That makes it a reference type rather than a value type. And so in your code, `LSA_UNICODE_STRING[]` is an *array of pointers*. But that is not compatible with the unmanaged `UserRights` parameter of type `PLSA_UNICODE_STRING` which is an *array of structures*.

Instead of

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private class LSA_UNICODE_STRING
{
    ....
}
```

you need to use

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct LSA_UNICODE_STRING
{
    ....
}
```

On the p/invoke, you should remove both the `SetLastError` and `PreserveSig` settings. They are not applicable here. The function does not call `SetLastError`, and there's no COM parameter re-writing.

Your declaration of `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES` is also quite wrong. You need it like so:

```
struct LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES
{
   public UInt32 Length;
   public IntPtr RootDirectory;
   public IntPtr ObjectName;
   public UInt32 Attributes;
   public IntPtr SecurityDescriptor;
   public IntPtr SecurityQualityOfService;
}
```

You'll need to marshal the `ObjectName` to a pointer to `LSA_UNICODE_STRING`.

It's very likely there are more issues, but that's all I can spot in a 10 minute review. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  On `LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES`, I was tired and being lazy because the docos stated that it was an unused arg in `LsaOpenPolicy` so I was just creating something of the right size to minimally satisfy the signature.  That part seemed to work, so for my own education, would you have expected otherwise on that one?

Comment: I did fix this last night, but the code is at home.  I'll post up my revisions later, for what little learning benefit there might be from that, for the next guy.

Comment: LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES is for sure an AV waiting to happen. The name field is a pointer. So it's going to get dereferenced. And that's an AV.

Comment: Ha!  Looks like I was just lucky that the ObjectAttributes parameter of `LsaOpenPolicy` is unused internally and one is directed in the docos to zero it out when initializing the structure.  The fact that I totally botched it's declaration seems to only have worker because I effectively zeroed a larger structure that I should have had, and the `ObjectName` field being null is what was desired in this case anyway.